# Is post data persistent through php header redirect?

Tags: php, forms, header

If I submit a form to a php page using post, can I use those post values on a page that I arrive at by using the `header('location: ...php')` redirect?

Example:

```
<form action="welcome.php" method="post">
   Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
   E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
   <input type="submit">
</form>
```

On welcome.php, if I do `header("Location: welcomBack.php")` can I still access `$_POST['Name']` and `$_POST['E-mail']`... (from `welcomeBack.php`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**NO**, you can't. Redirect to another page will mean to be in another page and no `$_POST` value nor `$_POST` array will be avaiable. In other hand you can still pass values throw the link itself and have available in the other page. For example

```
header('location: other.php?data=one');
```

So in the other page you can use

```
echo $_GET['data'];
//print one
```

As sidenote i would add you can redirect to another page with a form action and then have all values available in the other page in the `$_POST` array

Comment: How would I redirect to another page with a form action in the way that you're saying?

Comment: Please check documentation here http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_form_action.asp Just change your action from `action="welcome.php"` to `action="welcomeBack.php"`